# Why won't my Apple Software Updater connect to Apple?

Tags: itunes

Every morning, on one particular machine, I get a popup that iTunes has an update to install.  However, when I click download nothing happens.  If I try to use the Apple Software Updater manually it reports that the Apple Software Update Server cannot be found.  I have full Internet connectivity, having no problems getting to any other sites and my other machines on the network update iTunes just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a firewall rule in place that may be blocking access to the ASUS?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try downloading a full copy of iTunes rather than trying to update it: http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

Comment: Well, that got me the new version of iTunes, but my updater is still broken.

Comment: Brian Knoblauch - You should edit your original question to indicate that it  is the Apple Software Server that is not working, not just the iTunes update.